# Does Stack Overflow have a bloopers space?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sometimes we get the most funny questions, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451420/how-can-i-split-these-txt-files-and-display-the-contents-in-those-files-using-sh):
In order to explain how redirection works (write the result of a command to a file), I give following example:

```
Do_Something > resulting_file.txt
```

(with some explanation), and the person answers:

> i tried like this ... but its shows
> search.sh: line 1 :**Do_Something : command not found**

When I saw this remark, I just couldn't stop laughing for quite a long time :-)
So, if Stack Overflow has a bloopers chapter, I'd like to add this one :-)

Comment: A personal blog would probably be the best place for that content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, that's not what Stack Overflow is for. Highlighting someone's honest mistakes like your example would go against the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct); there is a **huge** difference between your friends and family lampooning a mistake you made versus enshrining such mistakes for all the world to see.

We [don't hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), but there are other places you can collect things that amused you, like a personal blog.

Comment: We do have an off-site resource: https://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/ ...

Comment: @rene The problem with that, in addition to most of it not being funny, is keeping up with the update-frequency.

Comment: @rene that’s not a Stack Overflow feature, that’s.... someone’s blog essentially.